# How to parse data to the ViewController from another class in an ios application

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, cllocationmanager, viewcontroller

I made an application to communicate with a REST API service. Now i need to send some gps coordinates to that service so i made another class in my application called MyCLController and i managed to get the coordinates of my position and also display them in a label in my app. What i am having trouble atm is this:

I don't know how to use the coordinates i get from the method :

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self.delegate locationUpdate : [locations lastObject];
    [CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[locations lastObject] coordinate];
    double dblLagitude = coordinate.lagitude;
    double dblLongitude = coordinate.longitude;
}
```

(which is implemented in my MyCLController class) into my viewcontroller where i developed the code to make a request to the server and send a string to the server. Anyone has any idea how i can declare  these two variables so i am able to use them in my viewcontroller or what can i do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to create properties in the MyCLController class and put the values in it from your current class?

Comment: When you say "to create properties" you mean ? I get the variables in the that method above which is contained in the MyCLController but i need to parse them in my Viewcontroller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create properties in `MyCLController`(in your .h file) as,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double dblLagitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double dblLongitude;
```

And your method should be modified as,

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self.delegate locationUpdate : [locations lastObject];
    [CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[locations lastObject] coordinate];
    self.dblLagitude = coordinate.lagitude;
    self.dblLongitude = coordinate.longitude;
}
```

You need to use the object of `MyCLController` in your viewcontroller and use the properties as `myCLController.dblLagitude` and `myCLController.dblLongitude`(assuming that the object of `MyCLController` is `myCLController`).

Comment: Hey really thanks i managed to be able to use the two variables in my view controller but there is one last thing now. I get 0.0000 values all the time although my display in my app show the real coordinates. Any idea?:O

Comment: Just found out that locationupdate is updating coordinates every second so if i apply an NSLog  to print my coordinates i just print the starting coordinates which are 0.0000 . So if i move my NSLog into my update location i get what i need. Thanks a lot for your help.!! Realy helped out!

Comment: Don't forget to call 'stopUpdatingLocation' so that your app doesn't drain battery unnecessarily.